# C# Isolated AzureFunction - AzureSignalRConnectionString

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-functions-isolated

I need to set the SignalR connection string in my startup code from a key vault secret. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/concept-connection-string#configure-a-connection-string-in-your-application) suggests to pass the connection string into `AddAzureSignalR(<connectionString>)` like this

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => services
        .AddSignalR()
        .AddAzureSignalR("Endpoint=https://my.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=<key>;Version=1.0;"))
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

Any SignalR function fails with

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.negotiate. 
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management: ServiceEndpoints is empty. ConnectionString is  null, empty, or consists only of white-space.
```

I tested this with the [isolated-bidirectionalchat](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples) sample app - after upgrading the nugets the same problem occurs.

Things I have unsuccessfully tried

- adding a new in-memory configuration source containing this setting
- using the full `options` for `AddAzureSignalR`, explicitly setting all endpoints and connection strings
- using other names following several posts on the net, like "SignalRConnection" etc ...

How can I set the `AzureSignalRConnectionString` from code instead of `local.settings.json`?